# How Do I Stop NFS Clients from Using All of the NFS Server's Resources?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I have a v4 NFS server running on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  It is the main repository for the web assets that four external nginx webservers mount to serve up to site visitors.  These client servers connect to it via a read-only mount.  Each of these RO servers has this displayed when I check the mounts:

> 10.0.0.90:/assets on /var/www/assets type nfs4 (ro,addr=10.0.0.90,clientaddr=0.0.0.0)

The NFS master's /etc/exports file contains entries like this for each server:

> /mnt/lvm-ext4   10.0.0.40(ro,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)

The problem that I'm seeing is that these clients are eventually utilizing all the RAM on the NFS server and causing it to crash.  If I do a `watch free -m` I can watch the used memory creep up until it's used and then see the free buffers/cache entry creep down to near zero before the server eventually locks up requiring a reboot.

There is some sort of memory leak somewhere that is causing this, and the optimal solution would be to find it and fix it, but in the meantime I need to find a way to have the NFS server protect itself from connected clients using all it's RAM.  There must be some sort of setting that limits the resources the clients can use, but I can't seem to find it.

I've tried adjusting the values for `rsize` and `wsize` but they don't seem to help or be related.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: How do you know that NFS is what's using all of the memory?

Comment: I guess I don't know for certain that it's nfsd that's consuming it all, but since the server has only a single service, other than sshd, nfsd is my primary suspect.

Comment: Why don't you try running top or gnome-system-monitor to find out what's using all the memory instead of assuming that its nfsd.